# Please explain the differences between those similar words

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

I came across with the unfinished sentence below:

Her bestie showed her true _______.

a. character

b. disposition

c. temperament

d. colors

e. nature

I know the correct answer is D for colors. But I don't understand why this is the correct answer because I think A for character works for me, and all the answers seem to have similar meaning. Can someone explain to me please?

Comment: It could be that the questioner is looking for an idiom— in which case only _colors_ fits.

Comment: 'I know the correct answer is D ... colors' is unhelpful. 'The only answer accepted as correct in the test is D (colors)' might be more tractable, but then unless the test added caveats, the test would be wrong.

Comment: All of the answers are "correct" in the sense that they make sense in the sentence.  I suppose that "colors" is preferred in this case because "bestie" is extremely informal - almost slang - and "colors" is likewise the least formal choice.

Answer (score 5):

This is a bad exercise because *character* and *nature* would also be valid in the literal sense.

To *show one's true colours* is a metaphor, referring to the tradition of a warship flying the flag of a different nation as a ruse to enable it to get close to an enemy ship. This was acceptable as long as it changed to the correct flag (its 'true colours') before attacking.